# Is it possible to express a circle/disc as a union of uncountably-many non-infinitesimal length line segments?

Tags: measure-theory

A square can be expressed as the union of uncountably many positive length line segments quite easily via drawing vertical segments from the top to the bottom.

A triangle can be expressed too, via drawing all the cevians from a vertex(drawing vertical segments does not work, since some segments have infinitesimal length)

But is it possible to express a disc this way?

Comment: Start with the center and draw radii.

Comment: In the case of the triangle, the vertical segments don't have ”infinitesimal" length. Most of the have positive length, some of them have length $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The same idea of the triangle work. Fix a point on the circumference $P$ and consider all the segments $PQ$ where $Q$   varies in all the other points of the circumference.

Comment: By “non-infinitesimal length”, I think that the OP means that all the lengths exceed a common positive lower bound. @Vasili's comment achieves this.$$\,$$Trivially, all lengths are either zero or non-infinitesimal (unless you believe in infinitesimals, in which case we are into a whole new story).